# Sequelize: how to do nested subquery in one to many field?

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I have two tables; one is "user" another is "post". User has a one-to-many relationship with "post". "post" has a foreign key field named user_id.

`user` table:

```
+----+--------------------------------------+--------+------------+-----------+------------------+----------+------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | uuid                                 | name   | first_name | last_name | email            | password | role | createdAt           | updatedAt           |
+----+--------------------------------------+--------+------------+-----------+------------------+----------+------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 | 37b4e543-ae46-45ef-a216-dea4ee79d6f7 | riyad  | 0          | 1         | riyad@gmail.com  | 123456   |    1 | 2021-11-22 17:56:56 | 2021-11-22 17:56:56 |
|  2 | d63c3414-db52-4784-9de8-b99a6659f1c9 | riyad2 | 6          | 7         | riyad2@gmail.com | 123456   |    5 | 2021-11-22 20:01:36 | 2021-11-22 20:01:36 |
+----+--------------------------------------+--------+------------+-----------+------------------+----------+------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

`post` table:

```
+----+---------+--------+---------+--------------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | title   | body   | user_id | slug                                 | createdAt           | updatedAt           |
+----+---------+--------+---------+--------------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 | title 1 | body 1 |       1 | 6e95b4a2-f101-48cd-8fea-8b53850c54b0 | 2021-11-22 17:57:56 | 2021-11-22 17:57:56 |
|  2 | title 2 | body 2 |       1 | 47d0cdbe-af3b-446a-badf-5197d8796133 | 2021-11-22 17:58:02 | 2021-11-22 17:58:02 |
|  3 | title 3 | body 3 |       2 | 347e200b-bffd-423d-b481-48d1b74ecc75 | 2021-11-22 20:02:04 | 2021-11-22 20:02:04 |
+----+---------+--------+---------+--------------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Now I want to get the users who posted from 2021-11-22 15:00:00 to 2021-11-22 20:00:00.

In this case the first two posts (post id 1 and 2) were made in this time which were posted by user_id 1. Now I want to get that user(s) details in single query.

This is the SQL query I would do like use:

```
select * 
from user 
where id = any(select user_id from post 
               where createdAt >= "2021-11-22 15:00:00" 
                 and created_at <= "2021-11-22 20:00:00")
```

Now how can I write that in sequelize?

Answer (score 0):

You want this [Sequelize doc page](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/sub-queries.html).

Long story short (at least in my opinion), sub queries will be hard to handle in any ORM. I would advise to use raw SQL instead.